# Oracle Forms With iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, oracle, oracleforms

I searched alot for oracle forms for iOS devices but i did'nt find a way to do that. Is there any to use oracle forms in iPhone or iPad ?
I read somewhere on a website that oracle forms need JRE as iOS devices didn't have JRE so it is not possible. But there are few applications using oracle forms so there must be a way.

Answer (score 1):

There is a company called [OraPlayer](http://oraplayer.com/) that promise to run forms from any mobile device.

Comment: Isn't there any other way to do so ?